# Nameserver propagation

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have recently changed the nameservers for my domain (from namecheap to yandex) but it's been almost 5 days and the changes haven't been detected over at yandex meaning I can't update the A record. Any ideas why propagation is taking so long? Someone else has access to the domain so I can't be sure whether it has been configured properly. Any help welcome.

https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=plantsandbeauty.co.ke&type=NS&useresolver=77.88.8.8&ns=all&nameservers=

Comment: Have you set the SOA to delegate authority to yandex? No record is showing up in `dig`.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/125378/37681: *""DNS propagation" isn't a real phenomenon, per se. Rather, it is the manifest effect of the caching functionality specified in the DNS protocol. Saying that changes "propagate" between DNS servers is a convenient falsehood that's, arguably, easier to explain to non-technical users than describing all of the details of the DNS protocol. It's not really how the protocol works, though."*

Comment: Did you decide to go back to namecheap for some reason?

Comment: Yes I did. Don't have the ability to edit the DNS records so I instead opted to have them update the A record.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have not properly delegated authority for the `plantsandbeauty.co.ke` domain to yandex.

As with all DNS providers, if you wish yandex to be the "authoritative" nameserver, you need to delegate authority to yandex *through the domain registrar* in order for the SOA record to be set.

Follow the instructions according to the [namecheap KB article](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/767/10/how-can-i-change-the-nameservers-for-my-domain), and set `dns1.yandex.net` and `dns2.yandex.net` under "Custom DNS." Once you have done that, you can [confirm ownership to yandex](https://yandex.com/support/domain/setting/confirm.html), following the yandex procedure and selecting the last method, "Delegate a domain to Yandex servers."

See additional yandex guidance [here](https://yandex.com/support/domain/domain/dns.html) and [here](https://yandex.com/support/domain/delegir.html).

Comment: Won't SOA be set after nameserver propagates? SOA as I gather will only be changed when Yandex verifies that I'm the owner of the domain - which should happen by simply changing the nameserver. Couldn't find fields for SOA on namecheap.

Comment: The SOA is set _only_ by the registrar. Go to wherever you bought the domain and set it/request it be set there. If it was any other way, your site could be hijacked by anybody setting up a nameserver. Read the ynadex documentation to which I pointed you; in the second link yandex tells you "The DNS servers must be specified in the domain settings on the registrar's website." Specifically, you set the SOA record there (although all you will do is identify the yandex nameservers there). Everything else will then be at yandex, including the NS records you already have, and the A records you will

Comment: The nameserver is _not going to propagate until you set establish a proper SOA_. And yandex will only _verify_ you are the owner by looking at the SOA record; it is your responsibility, not theirs.

Comment: Per [yandex](https://yandex.com/support/domain/setting/confirm.html), again. "You can confirm domain ownership after you register the domain with a registrar and add it to Yandex.Mail for Domain," however, as stated before, "You can add necessary DNS records for the domain before delegating it to Yandex servers if you have confirmed domain ownership. But [_these records will become effective only after delegation_](https://yandex.com/support/domain/domain/dns.html)."

Comment: Follow the instructions according to the [namecheap KB article](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/767/10/how-can-i-change-the-nameservers-for-my-domain) and set `dns1.yandex.net` and `dns2.yandex.net` under "Custom DNS"