# How can I point a wildcard subdomain to multiple servers?

Tags: wildcard

As a SaaS software seller, I offer separate cPanel accounts for my customers. My main domain is "domain.com", and I need to automatically create subdomains. However, the IP address is not being pointed to the hosted server. I created a wildcard "*.domain.com", but after the subdomains are created, they are not fully propagated. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Using what reverse proxy?

Comment: For starters : there is no DNS propagation, only caching of DNS records: https://serverfault.com/questions/125371/ and it may be a simple case of waiting for cached records to expire before you see changes.

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply. Some related topics may be asked on Webmasters

Comment: @hardillb iam using cpanel whm with regular dns system in whm